# Google maps and Angular material design dialog full width

Tags: html, google-maps, angular-material

I have inserted a map in in an md-dialog. It works, but I cannot get the map to fill the container.

I have "made" a codepen to illustrate my problem: http://codepen.io/neetsnp/pen/bqZQqd

The "fixed" map dialog uses these styles for the map:

```
  <div id="map2" style="width: 100%; height:200px"></div>
```

This is as far as I can get. But I would have liked to do:

```
   <div id="map" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></div>
```

It seems that it is only the height param that causes problems, as I can get the map to fill 100% width.

I hope someone knows how to do this, at the solution must work on all screen sizes.

Thanks,

Steen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding position absolute  to the div

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%;height:100%; position: absolute;"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmEJmz

Comment: Yup, that did it. Works both on the codepen and in the complete web solution. Thanks!